# Do while and try catch stuck in loop for user input validation/exception handling

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. I can't re-enter into the try block and ask the user to input again.

Commented out are a few things which I've already tried. But nothing has worked. Sometimes will get stuck in infinite loop. Thanks for your help!

```
public static int integerInput(String prompt,int min) {
    int value;
    String error, outStr;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    value  = min - 1;
    error = "ERROR value must be above " + min;
    outStr = prompt;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.println(outStr);
            value = sc.nextInt();
            outStr = error + "\n" + prompt;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //value = -1;
            //outStr = "ERROR input must be of type int" + "\n" + prompt;
            //value = -1;
            //value = sc.nextInt();
        }
        //value = - 1;

    }while (value < min);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Your code, unmodified, doesn't have any infinite loop. The method will return the value as soon as it's bigger than than or equal to the min value.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. So nothing needs to be in the catch block ie. min - 1? If I enter an invalid data type eg. "abc" my program will continue to output the prompt over and over instead of getting user the user input again.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread. I thought you were saying that it didn't work when you entered valid integer values.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your program is reading constantly the same line, that's why it stuck on do - while. It is reading the same line, because on exception

> the scanner's input cursor is reset to where it was before the call.

If you want it to move to another line add `sc.nextLine();` in your `catch` block.

About your attempt in `catch` block - your program again is reading the same line, but this time it is not in `try` block, so the same exception is thrown (`InputMismatchException`) and program stops. 
I would suggest you to catch this exactly exception instead of `Exception`.

Comment: Great thanks that worked. Saved me a lot of time! Cheers.